# Notepad++ Special Characters in Batch

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

So I'm making a thing in batch and when ever I run it instead of showing me a picture of either "≈" of "▓" it shows me "Γûô" or "Γëê" How do I fix this so that is shows me the special characters I want.
This code is below:

```
:Test

cls

set /a testa1num=%random% %%2

if %testa1num% == 0 set testa1=≈

if %testa1num% == 1 set testa1=▓

echo %testa1%

pause

goto Test
```

Comment: What encoding do you use saving with npp and what is your default code page `chcp /?`

Comment: The encoding is set to "Encode in UTF-8". and I don't know what my default code page is, or what it means.

Comment: As `chcp /?` mentions, type `chcp` without a parameter to display the active code page number. If you want UTF-8 code page, use the command `chcp 65001` at the top of the script. If the console font supports unicode, then it may display the characters as expected..

Comment: Change your text encoding to ANSI. Batch doesn't play nice with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to display special characters (like `áéó`) was to set the Encoding to `Western European` / `OEM 850` (Multilingual - Latin I). After that, Notepad++ matched the console (the special characters displayed "wrong"), so after fixing them they looked fine when running the batch file.

Based on the comment by @michael_heat, previously I ran `chcp` in a CMD window to be sure which encoding it is actually using. If for example yours is 437, you have to select `Western European` / `OEM-US`.